# Webpack: Why by default recommended bundle max size is 244 KiB?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Does anyone know how 244 KiB number was received? Just curious.

Comment: search the github repo. ask there if its not clear.

Comment: "Please ask questions on StackOverflow or the webpack Gitter" - I can't ask such questions in Webpack GitHub issue.

Comment: stack overflow is for programming *problems*. we aren't here to answer questions as to why certain libraries made their own decisions.

Comment: And searching the codebase I will most likely find some constant, not the reason, why exactly this limitation was chosen.

Comment: `git blame` on that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is actually 250kb - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/performance/#performance-maxentrypointsize

You can read about the reasoning [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3216):

> If we looked at tools like performancebudget.io, targeting loading in RAIL’s <3s on 3G would place our total JS budget at a far more conservative 106KB once you factor in other resources a typical page might include (like stylesheets and images). The less conservative number of 250KB is an upper bound estimate.

It is just an estimate based on trying to be performant on slow speed mobile devices, but is hard to achieve using many frameworks so is more of a guide.

Comment: Does this reffer to the non gzipped size or gzipped size?

Comment: Link doesn't mention this anymore :(